# How is dharma formed?

Tags: modern-world, mind, five-skandas, dharmas, sastras

I believe that the word 'dharma' (among other things) refers to the constituent elements of a body and mind, and that the Buddhist should find those dharmas void of a person, and perhaps any substantial quality whatsoever.

How is dharma formed?

"Form" is one of the skandhas, what a body-and-mind (I believe 'nama-rupa' in the sanskrit word for that?) has contact with in order to generate the rest of us.

Is there a Buddhist philosopher who talks or debates, perhaps at length, and ideally grounded in sutras, about how dharmas depend upon form?

I suspect there's a major / basic teaching on this, just wanted to make sure I'm not missing anything, when i research this question, which I find interesting because the contemporary world seems to make its ideas out of "form".

Comment: perhaps too broad as a question, sorry if that's the case

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are asking about [Dependent Origination](https://tricycle.org/magazine/dependent-origination/)?

You can find detailed information in "[Learning materials for Dependent Origination (Paṭiccasamuppāda) in Theravada Buddhism](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/48/471)".

For a perspective from the Abhidhamma, "[The Abhidhamma in Practice](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/mendis/wheel322.html)" may be helpful.